# How to setup a gradle multi module project? (Could not resolve project :moduleA.)

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

So I'm trying to setup a gradle multi module project.

My file structure looks something like this:

```
├── moduleA
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
└── moduleB
    ├── build.gradle
    └── settings.gradle
```

The **build.gradle** file of **moduleB**:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.3.60"
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':moduleA')
}
```

The **settings.gradle** for moduleB file:

```
include "moduleA"
```

It seams like everything works out, until i try to build **moduleB**.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :moduleA.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :moduleA:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I'm quite new to gradle and I don't really understand whats going on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs on multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), you should have a `settings.gradle` in the root project, rather than in each of the subprojects:

```
.
├── moduleA
│   └── build.gradle
├── moduleB
│   └── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

And include both subprojects in settings.gradle: `include 'moduleA', 'moduleB'`

Answer (score 2):

The **root project** `settings.gradle` is where you define the projects.

```
rootProject.name = "my-project

include("moduleA")
include("moduleB")
```